# too much vertical spacing in MathJax \overline{\overline{A}}

Tags: mathjax

when I type in MathJax a double \overline{\overline{A}},
I get too much vertical spacing.
Is it possible to reduce it in MathJax?

Mathjax example:
[image: Mathjax example]

Thanks very much.
Davide.

Comment: From your image, it looks like you are using MathJax v2.  The spacing is better in v3.  Can you switch to that?

Comment: Thank you @DavideCervone. No, I cannot switch to version 3 and I can't make any configuration.

Comment: Well, that makes things harder.  The best I can think of in that case is something like `\overline{\Rule{0em}{.85em}{0em}\smash[h]{\overline{\Rule{0em}{.65em}{0em}{\smash[h]A}}}}`.  You could use a definition like `\newcommand{\complement}[2]{\overline{\Rule{0em}{#1em}{0em}\smash[h]{#2}}}` to make things easier.  Then you can use `\complement{.85}{\complement{.65}A}` to get an A with two bars over it.